# How can I create columns in R when looping through a vector?

Tags: r, loops, stata

In R I'm trying to generate a summary dataframe displaying specific percentiles by group, whereby the name of the column in the summary dataframe depends on the name of the percentile.

My original dataframe is of the type:

| Month | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Feb | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| March | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| April | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |

I want to create a dataframe with 5th, 10th, 50th and 75th percentiles by month:

| Month | perc_5 | perc_10 | perc_50 | perc_75 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 5th perc | 10th perc | 50th perc | 75th perc |
| Feb | 5th perc | 10th perc | 50th perc | 75th perc |
| March | 5th perc | 10th perc | 50th perc | 75th perc |
| April | 5th perc | 10th perc | 50th perc | 75th perc |

In Stata I would have done this using a foreach loop, generating column names using by "` '"m, e.g.

```
foreach var of varlist:
    egen perc_`var'= pctile(column), p(`var')
```

I've been trying to do this in R using a for loop but haven't had any luck. I've also searched extensively on Stack Overflow but haven't been able to find an answer. Can anyone possibly advise?

Comment: So are the columns a,b,c,d different groups? or difference observations in the same group? Are you trying to generate the row-percentiles? How many columns does your real data have?

Comment: The Stata code is best ignored completely even if people answering know some or a lot about Stata. Sorry, but it makes no sense really and is a long way even from being legal.

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between the columns/values in the original data frame and the second data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you will have to put it in a group by, but here is a model to work from.  The data you presented (and I created) only has one value per month per column, so the concept of percentiles is undefined.

```
# create test data
df <- data.frame (m=letters, a=1:26, b=50:75, c=101:126)

# calculate your percentiles

f <- df %>% map_dfr( ~ quantile(.x, probs = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 0.75))) %>%
            bind_cols(f, col=names(df))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
    `5%` `10%` `50%` `75%` col  
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1   2.25   3.5  13.5  19.8 a    
2  51.2   52.5  62.5  68.8 b    
3 102.   104.  114.  120.  c
```